In children of ruin, what was Kern trying to hold back?
In one scene where Liff finally encountered the "witch" (Kern), Kern warns Liff that she (Kern) is holding back something horrifying. What was Kern doing? It never really seemed to come up again. I know that she was searching for Miranda but she wasn't really holding anything back?
